# GetContextTokenFromRequest always return null Sharepoint Hosted app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, office-addins

I'm tring to get the sharepoint context, but all the calls that I did the `GetContextTokenFromRequest` comes null from `TokenHelper`.

I checked my request URL and there is no query string for `"AppContext", "AppContextToken", "AccessToken", "SPAppToken"`.

My calls were made by `https`, I thought this was the problem but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint hosted add-in doesn’t need to get context token, because it is hosted by SharePoint, the code is only in HTML and JavaScript and no additional authentication for accessing SharePoint resources is needed. Provider-hosted SharePoint Add-ins include components that are deployed and hosted outside the SharePoint farm. You need to decide between OAuth and the cross-domain library to authorize your add-in’s access to SharePoint.

So if you are developing SharePoint hosted add-in , you  doesn’t need to get context token ; if you are developing a provider hosted add-in , you need to   check whether you have set the correct ClientID and Secret in the web.config of your web site.

Comment: The ClientID nd Secret in the web.config are ok, and the appManifest is ok, and I still have the problem.